# Java API for dynamic validation rules

Tags: java, validation, drools, rule-engine

Currently I'm looking for the best framework that can provide functionality for validate a bunch of data, for example validation for list of customer data, a customer data have several attributes like name, email, address, customer_type, SLA. the validator will validate the attribute's contents, like it's length, whether the value is null or not, its possible values (for multiple choice attribute), and any others logical validation.

For validation failure handler there is callback that will be invoke if there is any validation failure when validation process is still being processed or validator framework will return like ValidationResultSet that contains details of validation result at the end of validation process.

And the most important thing is that validation rules must be dynamic and configurable.

I'm considering **OpenL-Tablets** http://openl-tablets.org/ but still not sure about that, as it seems not really popular in term of it's community and how many projects that already use it.

Another Aspect that I consider are Java base, Community, Documentation, Integration, Scalability.

is **Drool** suitable for this case ?

There is any other suitable framework for this case ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The standard is to use Bean Validation, the reference implementation is Hibernate Validator.